# Как передать в форму select multiple?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код типа

```
<form action="" id="form">
    <select multiple name="">
        <option name="1" value="Y">1</option>
        <option name="2" value="Y">2</option>
        <option name="3" value="Y">3</option>
        <option name="4" value="Y">4</option>
        <option name="5" value="Y">5</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Таки как передать в форму параметры нескольких выбранных option ?
Чтобы в **get** улетело `1=Y&2=Y...`

Comment: может разные `value` им сопоставить

Comment: @darina Что значит разные `value`? как вы это представляете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте атрибут `name` и поскольку это множественный выбор то в конце имени вы должны добавить скобки `[]`. Что бы значения хранились в имени (массив).

```
<select name="select_name[]" multiple="multiple">
```

То что вы хотите сделать можно реализовать так.

```html
<form action="" id="form">
    <select multiple name="select_name[]">
        <option value="{1:'Y'}">1</option>
        <option value="{2:'Y'}">2</option>
        <option value="{3:'Y'}">3</option>
        <option value="{4:'Y'}">4</option>
        <option value="{5:'Y'}">5</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

А теперь подробно. Сейчас каждое значение представляет из себя строку `json`. И передав несколько значений, у вас на сервере будет массив у которого каждое значение строка `json`.

И на сервере уже вы можете сделать `json_parse` (если там `php`) и взять уже из значений `key=>val`.

Comment: Мне не совсем то нужно, так в форму идет name от select и value от option, а нужны option value и name.

Comment: @riyga Не пойму что вам конкретно нужно? Измените вопрос, сделайте как можно понятней. И еще одно тег `option` не имеет атрибута `name`.

Comment: Тоесть в форму этим способом не получится передать строку типа `option_name1=option_value1&option_name2=option_value2` ?А только `select_name=option_value1&select_name=option_value2` . Правильно понимаю?

Comment: @riyga да так не получится, смотрите ответ. Значения только идут на сервер из формы. А вы добавили по стандартам не существующий атрибут `name`, которое из себя нечего не значит для браузера.

Comment: @Raz Galstyan для select достаточно multiple, в [ ] нет необходимости

Comment: Я понял, спасибо